# How do I correctly use a multi-dimensional array in Eclipse Milo?

Tags: java, opc-ua, milo

I am writing a simple OpcUa client using milo and want to use multi-dimensional arrays as values.
Do I have to create an `ExtensionObject` to decode my matrix or is there an attribute to store the dimensions in? And if there is such an attribute, how can I access it?

Thanks

Chris

Comment: Is the Variable in the server you’re connected to actually holding a multi-dimensional array value?

Comment: Yes it is. I am using the milo example server and wanted to read out the double array contained in /arrayTypes/doubleArray (as I can see it in UaExpert) and already got the correct values. I am now trying to create a `VariableNode` object to asynchronously get the dimensions. Is this the correct way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I oversaw the `VariableNode.getArrayDimensions()` and `VariableNode.setArrayDimensions()` methods.